# Enable Cross Origin Scripting on Nginx from retina.js to load files from another URL?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, wordpress, amazon-s3

Im running a retina image plugin along with W3 Cache for CDN support. W3 cache moves images to S3, but the JS file won't server the files from there due to the difference in URL (it goes from h ttp://mysite.com to h ttp://assets.mysite.com)

I found a post which says to enable this just add this to your .htaccess

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CORS-enabled images (@crossorigin)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
# developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
# blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
# hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/
# wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/crossoriginAttribute
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and then the JS will be able to load the images from S3 - but I have no idea how to do this on Nginx. Could someone give me an easy example?

Original post this was form is - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/doesnt-work-with-cdn-w3-total-cache?replies=4

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to enable CORS rules at your S3 bucket, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors

simple rule that must work for you is:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Do i? Why in the above thread was enabling it in the .htaccess file of the server with the .JS file on the answer? Do I need to do both? Surely its the .js file on my server that needs to access the sub-domain name, as its that which is failing to bring the correct links.

Comment: Yep, JS files are server from your nginx server and images served from S3. Browser checks AllowOrigin header from images and not for JS, so you'll need to change S3 settins. IF images would be served by nginx only, add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'; would be enough.

Comment: Got you, ok cool, I put it on both and cross fingers.

Comment: Its not that, my buckets already have the CORS config as default on them… It must be that my nginx config just isn't working like the .htaccess file is in the thread above - I also have issues trying to get nginx .conf files to do anything as my server is also setup with app back and and reverse proxy front end .confs too.

Comment: Well, try adding add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'; to nginx, will it help? (this line have almost the same effect as yours .htaccess)

Comment: See the gist link in the answer below Andrei, I tried to put that into 3 of my Nginx .conf files but I didn't see any change for some reason - I can't see anything Id need to change on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640).  You will want to tweak it a bit for your domain and cache preferences.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this seems to be what I want and I've implemented it in the nginx.conf but its not allowing my js to call the files from the CDN still. Any ideas what might be going wrong - my server has a few .conf files, I will try another one to rule that out too...